# Error al usar clase con el diseño generada por pyuic

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

Estoy trabajando con Python 2.7 y PyQt, creo el UI con QtDesigner y convierto el código *.ui con pyuic4.

Al ejecutar el debugger me está devolviendo este error:

> GenieGUI' object has no attribute 'printSomething'

Así es como tengo el código:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_geniegui import Ui_GenieGUI

class GenieGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(GenieGUI, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = Ui_GenieGUI()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.ui.PathPushButton.clicked.connect(self.printSomething) # <-- error!

  def printSomething(self):
    print "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys

  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = GenieGUI()
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es hacer que tu clase `GenieGUI()` herede de `QMainWindow` y de `Ui_GenieGUI` (herencia múltiple) y luego creas o sobreescribes los métodos 
que quieras:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_geniegui import Ui_GenieGUI

class GenieGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_GenieGUI):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.PathPushButton.clicked.connect(self.printSomething)

    def printSomething(self):
        print "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys

  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = GenieGUI()
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias!