# Como conectar slots en PyQt5 desde otra clase

Tags: python, pyqt5

He generado un fichero `gen_Principal.py` a partir del `Principal.ui` y como no se debe modificar he creado otra clase **MiClase** para conectar las señales y slots ahí.

Quiero abrir una ventana cuando haga click en el menú. Actualmente se muestra la ventana principal y no da errores pero no abre la ventana nueva.

¿Alguien sabe qué está pasando? Gracias.

```
#Clase principal
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from gen_principal import Ui_MainWindow
from gen_otra import Ui_Dialog

class MiClase(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printSomething)
        self.actionclick_aqui_tambien.triggered.connect(self.abrirVentana)

    def printSomething(self):
        print("OK")

    def abrirVentana(self):
        print("Abriendo dialogo")
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication([])
    window = QMainWindow()
    main_window = Ui_MainWindow()
    main_window.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

#Clase generada
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(382, 267)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(382, 267))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(382, 267))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 382, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuClick_aqui_tambien = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuClick_aqui_tambien.setObjectName("menuClick_aqui_tambien")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionclick_aqui_tambien = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
     self.actionclick_aqui_tambien.setObjectName("actionclick_aqui_tambien")
        self.menuClick_aqui_tambien.addAction(self.actionclick_aqui_tambien)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuClick_aqui_tambien.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    # ...
```

Comment: Hola Jos, bienvenido a [es.so]. Es más simple si  heredas de tu clase `UI_MainWindow` directamente, mírate [Error al usar clase con el diseño generada por pyuic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39280/geniegui-object-has-no-attribute-printsomething/39335#39335)

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla , muchas gracias por el comentario. He probado tal y como sugeriste y guiándome por el enlace, pero sigue sin funcionar. No sé qué puede estar fallando :(

Comment: Jos pon un `print("Abriendo dialog...")` dentro del método `abrirVentana`, al principio, y mira a ver si te imprime en consola cada vez que pulsas el action del menú.

Comment: @FJSevilla no imprime

Comment: Pues no estás generando el evento...¿Podrías agregar el código de UI_MainWindow?

Comment: Ya está añadido @FJSevilla

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en:

```
app = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
main_window = Ui_MainWindow()
main_window.setupUi(window)
```

En ningún momento estas creando una instancia de `MiClase` que es tu ventana principal, estas creando un instancia de  `Ui_MainWindow`, sin lógica por tanto.

Simplemente puedes hacer algo así:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from core.gen_principal2 import Ui_MainWindow
from core.gen_otra import Ui_Dialog



class MiDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MiDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)


class VentanaPrincipal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VentanaPrincipal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printSomething)
        self.actionclick_aqui_tambien.triggered.connect(self.abrirVentana)
        self.dialog = None

    def printSomething(self):
        print("OK")

    def abrirVentana(self):
        print("Abriendo dialogo")
        self.dialog = MiDialog(self)
        self.dialog.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = VentanaPrincipal()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

También se crea una clase `MiDialog` que hereda de `Ui_Dialog` y que puedes usar para implementar la lógica de éste.

Comment: ¡Funciona!! ¡Muchísimas gracias!! :) @FJSevilla